# Is there a way to a conditional replace function with Regex

Tags: regex, conditional-statements, regexp-replace

Is there a way to use two different replace functions for one and the same regex operation depending on a given input?

I'm tracking parentheses within a dialogue or paragraph using the following regex:

```
(\([^)]+\))([^(<]+)
```

If a paragraph/dialogue begins with a parentheses…

> (smiles) Hello Jane, (quietly) How's the game?

the replace function should be

```
<br>$1<br>$2<br>
```

If the paragraph/dialogue only uses parentheses within the text…

> Hello Jane, (quietly) How's the game?

the replace function should be

```
$1<br>$2<br>
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you using Notepad++?

Comment: I'm using regex101.com to test regex, but will eventually add it to a bubble.io app

Comment: Ok, so conditional replacement won't work, only Boost (and PCRE2) support conditional replacement patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 different capture groups, one for the beginning of the string and the other when not using an alternation `|`

Then for the replacement, you would have to check for the presence of capture group 1 or group 2 to choose the right replacement.

Then your current group 2 will become group 3

```
(?:(^\([^)]+\))|(\([^)]+\)))([^(<]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VFowMG/1)

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, I'm not adept at regex. I tried with the following substitution (?1<br>$1<br>$2<br>:$1<br>$3<br>), but the output gets messed up. Mmh. Can you help me with that?

Comment: If I use `$1<br>$2<br>$3` as a substitution with **(smiles) Hello Jane, (quietly) How's the game?** I get `(smiles)<br><br> Hello Jane, <br>(quietly)<br> How's the game?` Why are there two "<br>" after "(smiles)"?

Comment: @Fabrizio What is the tool or language?

Comment: Hi The fourth bird, In the end, I'll be using bubble.io, that's where I'd like to add the regex code. But I haven't implemented the Regex code yet. So far, I just added the substitution on the Regex demo you provided.

Comment: @Fabrizio Does that mean that you can not use any code?

Comment: I have a JavaScript plugin for Bubble. So, you are saying with Regex alone this cannot be solved, is that right?

Comment: @Fabrizio I am afraid not by using a regex for Javascript alone. If you can use the capture groups using code, then you can check for the existence of group 1 and 2

Comment: I see, thank you very much for your time and expertise! Much appreciated.